# How do I equalise a set of DOM element heights after rendering a template using a knockout data-binding?

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using twitter bootstrap with knockout, and i am trying to resize the height of a set of elements in the rendered DOM after rendering a template using a foreach loop on an array returned from a computed observable. I have approached the problem initially by using the afterRender event, but I haven't managed to get the function to make the changes that I need.

I have a static case of what I am trying to achieve, so what I would really appreciate is some help using the foreach binding to make the height adjustments dynamically, after the computed observable is rendered.

Here is a fiddle of the static case. http://jsfiddle.net/lset/rr3ja/1/

Note the query at the bottom changing the height of .caption1 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can't really use the afterRender event as it will be called after each individual item is rendered, but you need to set the sizes after *all* the items have been rendered. One way you might do this is to have some property on the last item so that you can tell in the afterRender event that this is the last item (or you could probably just compare it to the last item in the list). You can then use this test to trigger your resizing of all the elements. In the past, I've just compared the index of the last item because I generally add an index property to all by observable arrays anyway.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I've realized that it won't work to use afterRender as you say, it is fired after each item is rendered. I've decided to put the problem to one side for the time being, but I will come back and follow up if I find a satisfactory solution. Cheers.